# ENVI raster file with nodata change to 0

Tags: gdal, envi, gdal-translate

I have a geotiff that I converted to a ENVI raster file with the following command:

> gdal_translate -of ENVI srtm_05_08.tif data.bil

The geotiff has water values supposedly set to nodata.  I am doing an interpolation on the data.bil file, and when I do, the water shows up at a height of about 32000m.  I am wondering if there is a simple way to change the nodata to be 0.  I tried:

> gdal_translate -of ENVI srtm_05_08.tif data.bil -a_nodata none

and

> gdal_translate -of ENVI srtm_05_08.tif data.bil -a_nodata 0.0

but neither of those seemed to work.

Is there an easy way to switch the data values?  I could do something like:
*if (val>5000) then val=0* 
but I am very much a beginner and don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 3):

NODATA is a tag, not a value.

If you only need to attach NODATA to a different value you can try:

```
gdal_edit -a_nodata NEWVALUE input.tif
```

You strip away NODATA tag (always helpful) with:

```
gdal_translate -a_nodata none
```

Finally, if you need to actualy change the value and reattach NODATA to it, you might try something like this:

```
gdal_calc -A input.tif --outfile=output.tif --calc="255*(A==0)" --NoDataValue=255
```

You can modify --calc part to suit your needs, it supports many things.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this thread](http://www.exelisvis.com/Support/Forums/tabid/184/forumid/6/postid/14740/scope/posts/Default.aspx). If you have access to ArcMap you could you the SetNull tool in Spatial Analyst as discussed [here](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009z0000000m000000.htm).

Comment: It would be helpful to include a summary of the first link in case the link goes away.